# How to merge querysets of different models with foreign key relation?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset, python-itertools

I am having  models in django with foreign key relation.I tried hard but unable solve the problem .I am having the queryset of `PropertyDetails` for that queryset i want to get all the values of `Filestore` where default image is **True**

```
class PropertyDetails(models.Model):
    propertyname=CharField(max_length=10)
    dateposted=CharField(max_length=10)

class Filestore(models.Model):
   propertyid = models.ForeignKey(PropertyDetails,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   defaultimage=BooleanField()
   imagename=models.CharField(max_lenth=10)
   imgproperty=models.Charfield(max_lenth=11)
```

for example 
Given:

```
(QuerySet [PropertyDetails: P1, PropertyDetails: P2])
```

Task:

```
for (PropertyDetails: P1)
    where defaultimage=True get values of 
       propertyname,values of filestore table combined with it 

(and same for P2)
```

The Response i want

```
{
  "id":1,
  "propertyname":"P1",
  "propertyimage":["imgproperty":"property","imagename":"abc"],

  "id":2,
  "propertyname":"P2",
  "propertyimage":["imgproperty":"property","imagename":"xyz"]
}
```

Is there any efficient solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `Serializer` for get json. 
First add related to field:

```
propertyid = models.ForeignKey(PropertyDetails,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='propertyid_set')
```

And define `Serializer` like this:

```
class PropertyDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      propertyimage = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

      def get_propertyimage(self, item):
        data = list(item.propertyid_set.filter(defaultimage=True).values('imgproperty', 'imagename'))
        return data

      class Meta:
        model = PropertyDetails
        fields = ['propertyimage', 'id', 'propertyname']
```

and use `PropertyDetailsSerializer` for your api